# Is there a function in R equivalent to textplot() for printing S4 objects to PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, r-s4, lme4, gplots

I have several random effects models fit by `lmer` (**lme4** package). For example:

```
a.1=lmer(songTrait ~ 1 + (1|Year) + (1|ID), REML=F)
a.2=lmer(songTrait ~ Date + (1|Year) + (1|ID), REML=F)
```

I would like to print the table summaries of these models, ideally, similar to the print out you get with

```
a.1
```

or

```
show(a.1)
```

This code...

```
pdf("c:/temp/x.pdf")
textplot(anova(a.1,a.2,method="ML"),cex=.8,halign="center",cmar=2)  
dev.off()
```

works fine to print the model comparison, but I would also like to print the detailed summary of each model (because I have 18 `songTrait` variables I'm fitting models for). Unfortunately, `textplot` (**gplots** package) can't handle S4 outputs, and I haven't figured out a good workaround. Any help would be much appreciated!